# Understanding WCF Multipart Soap service/endpoint with Attachment (SwA)

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, attachment, multipart

I'm trying to understand how to create/backwards engineer a Multipart WCF Soap endpoint that takes attachments as input parameters seperated by "MIME-delimiter".

I got an example of who requests to this kind of endpoint would look like  but i don't understand how to create the service to receive the request.

So the example i got was something like this (FYI I've removed information for security reasons):

```
--MIME11111.11111
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="" xmlns:eb="" xmlns:xsi="" xsi:schemaLocation="">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="2.0">
      <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="TYPE1">NUMBER</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:From>
      <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="TYPE2">NUMBER</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:To>
      <eb:CPAId>ID</eb:CPAId>
      <eb:Service eb:type="TYPE3">TEXT</eb:Service>
      <eb:Action>TEXT</eb:Action>
      <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId>ID</eb:MessageId>
        <eb:Timestamp>DATE</eb:Timestamp>
      </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <eb:Manifest eb:version="2.0">
      <eb:Reference xlink:href="cid:payload-1" xlink:role="aop:ROOT"/>
    </eb:Manifest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

--MIME11111.11111
Content-ID: payload-1

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aop:ROOT xsi:schemaLocation="" xmlns:aop="" xmlns:xsi="">
    <aop:ELEMENT>
        <aop:SUBELEMENT11>TEXT</aop:SUBELEMENT11>
        <aop:SUBELEMENT12>
            <aop:SUBELEMENT21>NUMBER</aop:SUBELEMENT21>
            <aop:SUBELEMENT22>NUMBER</aop:SUBELEMENT22>
        </aop:SUBELEMENT12>
    </aop:ELEMENT>
</aop:ROOT>
--MIME11111.11111--
```

What i have done so far is:

1. Created a WCF Project in Visual Studio.
2. Created my Interface like this:

   ```
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IService1
   {

      [OperationContract]
      [WebInvoke(Method = "Post", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/PostBusinessData")]
      PostBusinessDataResponseContract PostBusinessData(Manifest data);

   }

   [MessageContract]
   public class Manifest
   {
      [MessageHeader]
      public Headers MessageHeader { get; set; }

      [MessageBodyMember]
      public Stream Reference { get; set; }
   }

   [MessageContract]
   public class PostBusinessDataResponseContract
   {
      [MessageBodyMember]
      public string PostBusinessDataResponse { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Created my controller / service like this:

   ```
   public class Service1 : IService1
   {
       public PostBusinessDataResponseContract PostBusinessData(Manifest data)
       {
           return new PostBusinessDataResponseContract() { PostBusinessDataResponse = "It Works"};
       }
   }
   ```
4. My Header class was created by "special pasting" the XML structure between "header" elements from the example above.

I have the class Model for the soap-envelope header pretty much set up except some of the attributes on the elements instead show up as sub elements in the generated request structure.

But the main thing is that i don't quite understand how to built the code for the in parameter in regards to the attachment. It looks to me that the Attachment in the multipart example comes in as a stream, but as a stream of what? A file, a xml string/text? the only thing the reference in the SOAP envelope contains is a so called "Content-ID". No file name, nothing else.

How do i set up my endpoint in my backed to be able to consume the type of request shown in the example above is really my question.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I made a demo. After creating a WCF service, we can generate a proxy class to call the service by adding a service reference.

[image]

Right click References and select Add Service Reference.

[image]

Enter the address of the service in the address field, and click OK to generate the proxy class and configuration file for you to call the service.

```
      ServiceReference1.Service1Client service1Client = new Service1Client();
        string str = "Testing";        
        byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(array);
        Console.WriteLine(service1Client.PostBusinessData(stream));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The client-side can support the request type of the server through the generated proxy class.

[image]

This is the result.

**UPDATE**

WCF supports MTOM, which is the W3C standard superseded SwA.This is a link to MTOM related information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/mtom-encoding

For more information about MTOM and SWA, please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms996462(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

In WCF, if you want to receive the XML message you give, I think you can use message inspectors to intercept the XML message and parse it.

```
    public class ServerMessageLogger : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {

        string xml = ""+request;
       // Parse the received XML here
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

        string xml = ""+reply;
        //Encapsulate the XML to send
    }
}
```

For more information about message inspectors, please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: First of all Thank you very much for taking the time to go through this. Much appreciated! Secondly, am i correct in understanding that you are sending a string in the "reference" element? in the "receive" part of your last image there, i cant see the reference referring to an attachment in a second multipart section delimited by a "mime" delimiter. If you look at the example of request i got sent to me (first example of code snippet), you can see the "reference" part is referring to a trailing attachment of some kind.